# Include RNW file

Tags: r, latex, sweave

**Code**

```
\input{./A1_sample/sample.Rnw}
```

How to include Rnw file so that the R code in the file is executed? Using `\input` does not work.

Comment: You need to run the .Rnw file using R and one of the reproducible research packages (eg, Sweave or knitr). The Latex compiler does not know what to do with such a file, so putting its path in an \input command will result in an error. I open .Rnw files in rstudio and click the knitr button.

Comment: I'm using a main Rnw file. With something like \input I want to include the Rnw files so that each Rnw file executes automatically and added to the final TEX document.

Comment: You might want to have a look at knitr and the opportunity to use "child documents": http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/

Comment: I have never tried that and am unsure that it is possible. Certainly not with \input{}. I would suggest making the subfiles R scripts. You can run them, have them produce various objects, say an xtable object or a figure and then use those objects.

Comment: @Imo: I will try to do it in that way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The command is `\SweaveInput`.

Usage:

\begin{document}

\SweaveInput{PATH_TO_RNW_FILE/RNW_FILE.Rnw}

\end{document}

For further information see: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486298-Working-with-Multiple-Rnw-Files

Answer (score 0):

The `patchDVI` package provides various project management facilities for handling multiple file documents.  It requires a bit of setup, but works well in TeXShop or TeXworks.  Unfortunately I don't think RStudio can be easily customized to use it.

Your document `main.Rnw` would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
<<echo=FALSE,results="asis">>=
# .SweaveMake <- 2  # For complete make, uncomment this
.SweaveFiles <- c("file1.Rnw", "file2.Rnw", "file3.Rnw")
.TexRoot <- "main.tex"
@
\begin{document}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\input{file3}
\end{document}
```

Each of the `file*.Rnw` files would have a similar header, listing `main.Rnw` and other dependent files as `.SweaveFiles`.  Then the compiler can be told to run Sweave on all changed files and LaTeX on main.tex when it processes the file.